# Getting my J-1 authorised in the USA when I am travelling on an ESTA

Tags: esta, uk-citizens, j1-visas

I have a J-1 to start mid June 2016. I entered the USA to travel 28 days before its start date and had to get an ESTA. At the border they wouldnt do anything with my j1 as I am visiting at the moment.  How do I get the authorisation for my J-1 while I am in the USA?

Comment: Are you close to a border? Could you bus out and in again, maybe a day in Vancouver/Tijuana/Toronto, for example?

Comment: So are you saying I have to leave and re-enter? Can it not be done within the USA. I got my j-1 in Toronto (was studying in Canada but I am British) so all ok and I understood I could enter the USA within 30 days of the j-1 starting

Comment: I don't actually know, otherwise I'd have posted an answer. But generally the easiest way is to exit/reenter for changing visas, in my experience, even my Vancouver flatmates went to the border on a Monday night, 'left' and reentered on their new visa.  There may be other easier ways, but it was more to open options.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It's so confusing.  When you are told you can enter within 30 days but it's not made clear what happens about the j-1!

Comment: You can enter on the J-1 30 days _before the start of your academic program_.

Comment: Yes, that's what it says but mine is to work in a summer camp and at the border the guy wouldn't do anything with it despite me being within the 28 days.  He made me get an ESTA (I had got a different visa on for visiting) and said I was a tourist and not there to work at the moment. I thought I had done it right but clearly not and nothing on line tells you what to do! baffled!!!

Comment: "I had got a different visa on for visiting": what does that mean? What kind of visa was it? It sounds a bit like the border agent may have screwed up.  What are the program dates on your DS-2019 and what are the dates on your J-1 visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The procedure you are referring to is called a [Change of Status](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status) (CoS in us-immigarion speak). It is explicitly forbidden to do a CoS, when admitted via [visa waiver](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) (ESTA) (see previous link as well).

The best way would be go out of the country for a short while (Canada, Mexico, most of the Caribbean islands), obligatory surrendering your I-94W (if you are given any) and reentering on J-1 in time. When entering U.S. you will have to specifically request being admitted as J-1. They will likely send you through a secondary inspection (if entering by land), talk to you, and issue you a paper I94w (if entering by land). Remember to keep it with you and surrender upon leaving the U.S.